# Rendering issue with Raylib in WSL

Tags: c, windows-subsystem-for-linux, raylib

I'm creating a donkey kong like game and as of right now am just trying to render in both the background and the player character. The .png files(as texture2Ds) seems to render in correctly, but another wider and distorted image renders on top of it. The same code works on other non-WSL computers

[Here is what renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m57ho.png)

Here is my main game loop, but I'm not sure if any of the code is the issue as it works on computers that are not using WSL

```
    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)) {
            bunny->velocity.x = 0.7;
        } else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)) {
            bunny->velocity.x = -0.7;
        } else {
            bunny->velocity.x = 0;
        }

        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_UP)) {
                bunny->velocity.y = -0.7;
        } else {
                bunny->velocity.y = 1;
        }

        BeginDrawing();
            printf("A\n");

            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            DrawTexture(background, 0, 0, RAYWHITE);
            printf("B\n");
            DrawSprite(bunny);
            printf("C\n");
            UpdatePhysics(bunny, 0, otherSprites, 6, lines, count);
        EndDrawing();
        count++;
    }
```

I have tried rendering the sprites in different order etc. but nothing I am changing within the code seems to be working.

Comment: Any sort of GUI/graphics from the WSL container is going to be flaky at best, you can install an X Server on the windows host side and connect the $DISPLAY output from the WSL instance to the X Server for some GUI apps to work but it is a hack at best still (GPU support in WSL is still WIP I believe).  Your best bet is working native when comes to GUIs, for CLI programs or services/APIs WSL is fine, but likely more trouble than is worth doing the cross platform graphics.

As another alternative consider using VirtualBox or other full system virtualization options (GPU passthrough limited)

Comment: Also consider trying the Raylib discord, from some searching around it seems others have made this work, but my experience trying to run other graphical apps from WSL tells me it is trouble either way... this SO post may make more sense as an issue/bug report to WSL and/or Raylib projects since is a pretty specific reproduction of an issue outside of your code.

Comment: @shaunhusain We're doing this in class as kind of an introduction to c, so I'm more or less brand new to WSL and c in general. I'll check out the discord and see if there has been any similar issues. Thanks!

Comment: Oh gotcha.  Yah unfortunately from what I've seen from a friend doing computer science courses now they seem to throw people into the deep end with regard to system configuration and trying to run on virtualized platforms, Docker is great to learn and in general virtualization/containerization works well for APIs or CLI type applications but graphical layer is hairy business on any OS let alone cross OS :)

Comment: Would suggest if can get your hands on one pick up a Raspberry Pi or similar small computer that can run linux native so can use that in cases where need a linux native computer to try some stuff on ( can also explore using "Dual boot" or having more powerful dedicated linux machine but Pis are generally a cheap way to get in the door)